# How to Remove Private browsing from firefox V44

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, private-browsing

Is there a way to remove the entire option or just to disable private browsing in firefox V44.0(linux). I serched in google and sould only find answers or older version of firefox.
I also tried "Disable Private Browsing" plugin which for some reason keep on crashing my browser and that to reinstall firefox.
I would prefer to remove it altogather but am only fine to disable it using addons.

Comment: just curious, why would one want to do this? you can simply not use it if it's not needed, right?

Comment: @Sarge Borsch I just want to prevent someone from hiding what they are searching.

Comment: This won't work. There's always a way to clear history, private mode just automates that. Your better bet is to use a keylogger. However, it might be illegal.

Comment: @SargeBorsch   can you suggest some good keylogger for ubuntu/ firefox. I own the system so will it then be considred illegal???

Comment: I highly doubt that anyone on this site is going to recommend a keylogger, for any purposes…

Comment: i did search for  keylogger for linux with gui but could not find any. Where do u suggest i should ask?

Comment: I suggest looking at your problem from a different perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested the add-on [Disable Private Browsing Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/disable-private-browsing-pl/), which appears to do what you want and doesn't seem to crash for me using 44.0.2:

[image]

Comment: But if you disable the add-on you are back where you started, right. Whether that matters depends on the reason you want to do this.

Comment: @user3169 Bit of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) this, really :)

Comment: @user3169 this is the only thing that works on newer versions of firefox and to disable you will have to goto safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

Private browsing is "baked into" Firefox. The only way to remove it would be to acquire the source code (which could be done) and remove the feature and recompile your own custom version which is a massive undertaking with potential unforeseen bugs and problems.

A better course of action would be to find out why Firefox is crashing when you run in private browsing.

- Do you have any addons or extensions installed? Try removing all
  addons and running stock Firefox.
- Have you tried completely purging Firefox from the system and
  reinstalling?

Comment: my main goal is to disable private browsing. so i install the add on (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/disable-private-browsing-pl/) which caused firefox to crash.  is there any other way to disable private browsing